# How to add javascript in php code function.php error

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, lazy-loading, custom-wordpress-pages

This is a script that I want to initialize to my website: https://css-tricks.com/lazy-loading-responsive-adsense-ads/ I upload these script to my server and give address in the footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/js/jquery.adsenseloader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/js/adsenseloader.js"></script>
```

The next step is to initialize it on the WordPress website and the problem is when I trying to add it in function.php it shows me an error:

The error is

> Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 218 of file wp-content/themes/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.
> syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR), expecting end of file

I am interested in how to add this code in PHP?

```
// vanilla
var instance = new adsenseLoader( '.adsense' ); // accepted argument types: Selector String, Element, NodeList, Array
 
// jQuery
$( '.adsense' ).adsenseLoader();
```

Comment: ___it shows me an error___ Can we see the error? PLease

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the 
[Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 218 of file wp-content/themes/menshairstyletips/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.

syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR), expecting end of file

Comment: THats a PHP Error and you are showing us a tiny fragmant of Javascript. Please show us enough of the code to be able to see what you are doing

Comment: Why would you try and insert JavaScript code into your functions.php in the first place? Sounds like this much rather belonged into either the header.php or footer.php of your template?

Comment: I have added this source of the script in footer: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/js/jquery.adsenseloader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/js/adsenseloader.js"></script>`
but i need to initialize it and show it correctly because i need this code in function PHP :
`// vanilla
var instance = new adsenseLoader( '.adsense' ); // accepted argument types: Selector String, Element, NodeList, Array
 
// jQuery
$( '.adsense' ).adsenseLoader();`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to add code in function.php

```
add_action('wp_head','addsense_script');
function addsense_script(){
$script = "<script>";
$script .= "var instance = new adsenseLoader( '.adsense' );";
$script .= "$( '.adsense' ).adsenseLoader(); ";
$script .= "</script>";
echo $script;

}
```